# How to begin at line n in a file with sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

When using `sed` as `sed -i 's/pattern/replacement/g' ./file.txt`, how can I tell `sed` to skip the first 10 lines of a file, and begin the replacements on the 11th line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use address before `s` command in `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak '11,$s/pattern/repalcement/g' file
```

Here `11,$` will skip first 10 lines and start replacement from 11th line onwards.

Comment: What is the `.bak` for?

Comment: @Village Create backup file, when original file is over written (-i).

Comment: I prefer using `.bak` to keep a backup of original in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Same with `awk`

```
awk 'NR>10 {gsub(/pattern/,"repalcement")}1' file
```